# python BeautifulSoup find span id name without using string\re methods

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, beautifulsoup, html

I'm trying to get the id name of my span tags.

```
<td vAlign="top" colSpan="2"><IMG height="25" src="images/spacer.gif" width="1"><br>
    <!--start table details-->
    <table cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="5" width="100%" bgColor="#a18c42" border="0" id="compDetails">
        <tr bgColor="white">
            <td class="rowName" noWrap>מספר תאגיד:</td>

            <td width="100%" colSpan="3"><span id="lblCompanyNumber">520000472</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgColor="white">
            <td class="rowName" noWrap>שם תאגיד (עברית):</td>
            <td width="50%"><span id="lblCompanyNameHeb">חברת החשמל לישראל בעמ</span></td>
            <td class="rowName" noWrap>שם תאגיד (אנגלית):</td>
            <td width="50%"><span id="lblCompanyNameEn"></span></td>

        </tr>
        <tr bgColor="white">
            <td class="rowName" noWrap>סטטוס:</td>
            <td width="50%"><span id="lblStatus">פעילה</span></td>
            <td class="rowName" noWrap>סוג תאגיד:</td>
            <td width="50%"><span id="lblCorporationType">חברה ציבורית</span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr bgColor="white">
            <td class="rowName" noWrap>סוג חברה ממשלתית:</td>
            <td width="50%"><span id="lblGovCompanyType">חברה  ממשלתית</span></td>
            <td class="rowName" noWrap>סוג מגבלות:</td>
            <td width="50%"><span id="lblLimitType">מוגבלת</span></td>
```

lets say htmlSpan contains the html above -

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlSpan , fromEncoding="windows-1255") # I want to use windows-1255 and not utf8
spans = soup('span', limit=30)
```

that's the output -

```
[<span class="mainTitle">╫¿╫⌐╫¥ ╫פ╫ק╫ס╫¿╫ץ╫¬</span>,
 <span class="subTitle">╫ñ╫¿╫ר╫ש
            ╫ק╫ס╫¿╫פ/╫⌐╫ץ╫¬╫ñ╫ץ╫¬</span>,
 <span id="lblCompanyNumber">514568245</span>,
 <span id="lblCompanyNameHeb">╫£╫ס╫ש╫נ ╫נ╫ש╫á╫ר╫ע╫¿╫ª╫ש╫פ ╫ץ╫á╫ש╫¬╫ץ╫ק ╫₧╫ó╫¿╫¢╫
ץ╫¬ ╫ס╫ó"╫₧</span>,
 <span id="lblCompanyNameEn">LAVI INTEGRATION &SYSTEM; ANALYSIS LTD</span>,
 <span id="lblStatus">╫ñ╫ó╫ש╫£╫פ</span>,
 <span id="lblCorporationType">╫ק╫ס╫¿╫פ ╫ñ╫¿╫ר╫ש╫¬</span>,
 <span id="lblGovCompanyType">╫ק╫ס╫¿╫פ ╫£╫נ ╫₧╫₧╫⌐╫£╫¬╫ש╫¬</span>,
 <span id="lblLimitType">╫₧╫ץ╫ע╫ס╫£╫¬</span>,
 <span id="lblStatusMafera"><b><font color="Red"></font></b></span>,
 <span id="lblMaferaDate"></span>,
 <span id="lblStatusMafera1"><b><font color="Red"></font></b></span>,
 <span id="lblCountry">╫ש╫⌐╫¿╫נ╫£</span>,
 <span id="lblCity">╫ק╫ף╫¿╫פ</span>,
 <span id="lblStreet">╫פ╫£╫£ ╫ש╫ñ╫פ</span>,
 <span id="lblStreetNumber">34</span>,
 <span id="lblZipCode">38424</span>,
 <span id="lblPOB"></span>,
 <span id="lblLocatedAt"></span>,
 <span id="lblCompanyGoal">╫£╫ó╫í╫ץ╫º ╫ס╫¢╫£ ╫ó╫ש╫í╫ץ╫º ╫ק╫ץ╫º╫ש</span>,
 <span id="lblCompanyDesc"></span>,
 <span id="lblDochShana"></span>]
```

I know how to get the span content but I can't get the span id name ('lblStatus' for ex').

how can I get it with BeautifulSoup's methods?

I'm also having trouble saving the spans content without BeautifulSoup converting (charset) it to utf8 (or gibberish) in the end I need to save the the span id name and content into a csv, and I'm having utf8 problems with it.

Thanks

Comment: @YSY - I see you have read the answers... did any of those helped you? If yes, upvote the helpful ones. If one in particular solved your issue, don't forget to mark it as "accepted" (sorry if you know this already, but seeing you are new to the site...)

Answer (score 1):

You can [access the attributes of tags](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#The%20Parse%20Tree) by looking up the tag as a dict, keyed by tag name:

```
for span in spans:
    print span['id']
```

gives what you want: `lblCompanyNumber lblCompanyNameHeb lblCompanyNameEn lblStatus lblCorporationType lblGovCompanyType lblLimitType...`

> *I'm also having trouble saving the spans content into a csv without BeautifulSoup converting (charset) it to utf8 (or gibberish)*

mac's answer to use decode() is correct. It's unrelated to `sys.getdefaultencoding()` which defaults to 'ascii', that doesn't matter.

Comment: I've 'fixed' the encoding problem with -

Comment: I've 'fixed' the encoding problem with - span.getText().encode('windows-1255', 'ignore') 

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> **I can't get the span id name ('lblStatus' for ex').**

Using `spans` as set by your own code:

```
for span in spans:
    print span['id']
```

> I'm also having trouble saving the spans content without **BeautifulSoup converting to utf8 or gibberish**

I could not replicate this: the output of `spans` for me is not gibberish, but the same chars as in the html. Are you sure the page you are trying to parse is encoded in "windows-1255"? Do you have a proper UTF-8 encoding declaration (`# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-`) you your python file?

UTF-8 is pretty much the standard in python nowadays and BeautifulSoup uses it internally. My suggestion would be to work in UTF-8 in all your code and change encoding (if you truly need to do it) only when you output/dump data.

> **in the end I need to save the the span id name and content into a csv...**

This is just a rough idea that you should tweak as per your need:

```
import csv
file_ = open('output.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(file_)
for span in spans:
    writer.writerow([span['id'], span.string])
```

> **...and I'm having utf8 problems with it.**

Could you specify about what your problems are? On my system (GNU/Linux) it works just fine.